# How to copy results of a plugin to another project?

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

In Frama-C, I would like to copy the results of a plugin like Value from one project to another. How exactly do I do this? I'm guessing I have to use Project.copy with the proper State_selection, but what would that be for Value? More generally, how do I determine what the State_selection would be for a given plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no unified mechanism across plug-ins for that. For the EVA<sup>1</sup> plug-in, you would probably do something like

```
let selection = State_selection.with_codependencies Db.Value.self in
Project.copy ~selection ~src dest
```

in order to capture EVA's state as well as the intermediate states on which it depends.

That said, I'd advise against trying to copy such a substantial part of Frama-C's internal state. It's very error-prone and implies working with arcane API. If you can afford it, two other solutions seem easier:

- work in the original project, possibly creating a new project with a new AST as a result, through the `File.create_copy_from_visitor`.
- copy the entire project with `Project.copy` and work on the new project.

<sub><sup>1</sup>: **E**volved **V**alue **A**nalysis, the new name of Value</sub>